# Is recursive query slow?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

My manager asked me not to use recursive query since recursive by default means slow he claimed.

I'm just wondering if recursive query slow and if there is any other alternative way.

EDIT:
I'm talking about recursive query in general. My manager just told me to stop using recursive. His claim was in C# recursive function is slow. So don't use recursive query on Oracle which could be slow as well.

Comment: Show us what you want to achieve, and how you're currently doing it, and we may have a chance of suggesting alternative ways.

Comment: How many rows in query? Have your query indexed? How many times you peform this query? I think that question is a little ambigous.

Comment: I'm talking in general. Is recursive query generally slower and should be avoided?

Comment: Your manager clearly does not know what he is talking about.  To attempt to apply lessons from one language to a completely different scenario in a completely different type of language is an exercise in futility.

Comment: That is a great bouncing load of bosh. I strongly encourage disregarding your manager's programming advice to whatever extent is possible. Whether or not recursive queries are appropriate, that's a terrible justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In matters of performance, only benchmarks matter.  Guesses and analogies are worthless.

There is no absolute reason why recursive queries should perform badly, just because they are recursive.  What usually happens is that recursive queries get more expensive against larger data sets than a non-recursive query against a table of a similar size.

This is not an argument for never using recursive queries: it is an argument for testing our CONNECT BY queries against representative data volumes and seeing whether we might have a performance problem.  The mechanisms for avoiding recursive queries (for instance maintaining tables to store a flattened hierarchy ) have their own cost profiles.

If you want to learn some more about alternative to recursive queries, I answered a related question a while back.  [Check it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391809/creating-a-flattened-table-view-of-a-hierarchically-defined-set-of-data/3396499#3396499)   .

Comment: +1 *Informed* guesswork can sometimes be valuable when optimising queries, but a false analogy drawn against something that isn't even an RDBMS is PHB-behaviour at its pointiest.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive in general doesn't have to be slow.

I would consider the simple fact that someone utters such a general pseudo fact as proof that he should be ignored in that matter.

If you write recursive code, you don't know much about what actually gets executed. A lot of things might happen between your source code and what actually gets executed.

That said: There are many cases where recursion IS slow, or consumes lots of memory or causes a stackoverflow.

But often recursion is the obvious simplest solution.

So if you encounter a problem where you think: I can solve that using recursion. Do it.

Then test if performance and scalability are appropriate. If they aren't you can use the recursive implementation as a [test oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_%28software_testing%29) while tuning the solution (possibly by removing the recursion).