# Flatten recursive hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design, hierarchical-data

I have the following recursive query:

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(object_name, '\') AS path
FROM user_group_nodes
START WITH parent_id = '2892107544AA2278166C1AA8D123E761'
CONNECT BY parent_id = PRIOR object_id
ORDER SIBLINGS BY object_name;
```

Which returns the following sample dataset:

```
\UserGroupA\UserGroupAA\UserGroupAAA\JaneDoe
\UserGroupA\UserGroupAA\UserGroupAAA\UserGroupAAAA\UserGroupAAAAA\JohnDoe
```

Based on the above sample dataset, I need to insert the following records into a table:

```
Group            User
---------------  ---------------
UserGroupA       JaneDoe
UserGroupAA      JaneDoe
UserGroupAAA     JaneDoe
UserGroupA       JohnDoe
UserGroupAA      JohnDoe
UserGroupAAA     JohnDoe
UserGroupAAAA    JohnDoe
UserGroupAAAAA   JohnDoe
```

Can someone provide direction on how to accomplish this? I'm leaning towards using a cursor, but I'm hoping there is another option that performs better since I need to do this across 10,000 users and 1,500 groups.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a flattened table/view of a hierarchically-defined set of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391809/creating-a-flattened-table-view-of-a-hierarchically-defined-set-of-data)

Comment: You're describing a technique called Transitive Closure.  Read my answer to the question linked above for some insight and a useful resource.