# Force Oracle to use filtering in START WITH from outside of query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, database-performance, connect-by

Table definition:

```
  create table Tree
  (node varchar2(20),
  parentNode varchar2(20),
  val number);

  create index idx_tree_01 on Tree
  (node );
   create index idx_tree_02 on Tree
  (parentnode);
```

Sample data:

```
Insert into TREE (NODE,PARENTNODE,VAL) values ('2','1',2);
Insert into TREE (NODE,PARENTNODE,VAL) values ('3','2',3);
Insert into TREE (NODE,PARENTNODE,VAL) values ('4','2',3);
Insert into TREE (NODE,PARENTNODE,VAL) values ('5','4',1);
Insert into TREE (NODE,PARENTNODE,VAL) values ('6','3',1);
```

View definition:

```
 create view tree_view as 
     select connect_by_root parentnode as firstNode,
      lpad(' ', 2 * level - 2, ' ') || val as MyVal,
      node, parentNode
   from tree 
   start with parentnode in ( select parentnode from tree) 
   connect by parentnode = prior node
```

Now I want to execute the query:

```
select * from tree_view 
where firstNode = '1'
```

The execution plan for the query is :

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name        | E-Rows |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |             |        |
|*  1 |  VIEW                                    | TREE_VIEW   |      5 |
|*  2 |   CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH|             |        |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                     | TREE        |      5 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | IDX_TREE_02 |      1 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("FIRSTNODE"='1')
   2 - access("PARENTNODE"=PRIOR NULL)
       filter( IS NOT NULL)
   4 - access("PARENTNODE"=:B1)
```

As you can see the  `filterfirstnode = '1'` is used at the end. I want it to be used as the first thing..

I **CAN NOT** modify the view (I can only add maybe some hints).

How can I give hint to Oracle to use firstNode value in START WITH?  It would give great performance improvement.

My real "tree" table is a couple of tables and data volume is huge.
As I mentioned I cannot modify the view.

Do not propose me:

- function with firstnode parameter and pipelined result
- modification of view to use session context in start with
- temp table queering in start with
- etc.

**The view has to be the same.** The hints are only allowed.

Comment: @PavelGatnar I wouldn't ask here when there would be such possibility. The project is live - the bigger modifications are not allowed.

Comment: It's just sample. In the reality there is result from some other table. Please note my question is how to move filtering to START WITH from outside of query.

Comment: did You managed to solve this? Can You tell which hints did You try?

Answer (score 1):

`first_node` is a column in the view which is generated by `connect_by_root()` operator. The [documentation says of this operator:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators004.htm#SQLRF0031)

> You cannot specify this operator in the `START WIT`H condition or the `CONNECT BY` condition.

So there isn't anyway to achieve what you want. If you think about it, this is not unreasonable: to derive the first node the query *must* traverse the entire hierarchy to find the root node for each leaf.

One tuning approach - although probably not one open to you - is to materialize the hierarchy using transitive closure. Check out [this other SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396499/146325)

Comment: What about recursive CTE ? Do you think it's possible there?  `with tv (firstNode, val, node ,parentNode, lvl) as (
     select  parentnode as firstNode,
       val ,
      node, parentNode, 0 as lvl
   from tree 
   union all
   select tv.firstNode, tr.val, tr.node, tr.parentNode, lvl + 1 from  tv
    join tree tr
    on tv.node = tr.parentnode )
    select * from tv where firstNode = '1'`

Comment: @APC, can You review my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try create PIPELINED function to return view rows

```
CREATE TYPE t_row AS OBJECT (
  first_name  VARCHAR2(1000),
  my_val      VARCHAR2(1000)
  ... 
  );

CREATE TYPE t_tab IS TABLE OF t_row;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_hierarchy RETURN t_tab PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN (SELECT ...) LOOP
      PIPE ROW (t_row(rec.firstNode, rec.myval, ...));
    END LOOP;
RETURN;
END get_hierarchy;
```

and rewrite query

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(get_hierarchy)
```

Comment: I wrote that it's not solution for me in the question. Sorry you wasted your time writing the answer.

Comment: @dcieslak But you can use unmodified view inside function's select, why not?

Comment: The way how it 's called has to stay the same. Your solution was first what I proposed to customer but it was rejected. The next one was using application context - the view stays - but it was rejected too. I guess APC is right and it's not possible to tune it..

Comment: @dcieslak I understand now. It's appropriate to delete my answer?

Comment: You can keep it. I will up-vote everything at the end what makes sense and may be useful for somebody else.

Comment: @hinotf, kind request to review my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would You be satisfied with this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM tree_view 
START WITH firstNode = '1'
CONNECT BY parentnode = PRIOR node

 Plan Hash Value  : 2532164387 

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                    | Name        | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                             |             |    5 | 10090 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
|   1 |   HASH UNIQUE                                |             |    5 | 10090 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 2 |    CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH SW (UNIQUE)  |             |      |       |      |          |
|   3 |     VIEW                                     | TREE_VIEW   |    5 | 10190 |    4 | 00:00:01 |
| * 4 |      CONNECT BY NO FILTERING WITH START-WITH |             |      |       |      |          |
|   5 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                      | TREE        |    5 |    35 |    3 | 00:00:01 |
| * 6 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | IDX_TREE_02 |    1 |     2 |    1 | 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
------------------------------------------
* 2 - access("T"."PARENTNODE"=PRIOR "T"."NODE")
* 2 - filter("FIRSTNODE"='1')
* 4 - access("PARENTNODE"=PRIOR "NODE")
* 4 - filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TESTER."TREE" "TREE" WHERE "PARENTNODE"=:B1))
* 6 - access("PARENTNODE"=:B1)
```

The difference is in line 4: `filter( EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM TESTER."TREE" "TREE" WHERE "PARENTNODE"=:B1))`
This query returns duplicated data. `DISTINCT` is necessary to keep the same result set.